# Getting following error?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When I use:

```
var nic = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
```

I Include `using System.Net.NetworkInformation;`

I get this error:

```
'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface' does not contain a definition for 'NetworkInterfaceType'
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You are more likely to get answers if you use a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning an enumeration type to a variable in this line:

```
var nic = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
```

Try using one of the values of this enumeration type:

```
var nic = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType.Unknown;
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype.aspx) article for more information on this enumeration type.

**Edit**

Try removing the `NetworkInterface` prefix:

```
var nic = NetworkInterfaceType.Unknown;
```

Comment: i get this error 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface' does not contain a definition for 'NetworkInterfaceType'

Comment: You get what error? Please be clear with what you are asking and provide all of the relevant details.

Comment: When i use NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType i get this error  'System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface' does not contain a definition for 'NetworkInterfaceType'

Comment: @Ajay: That is a separate question altogether.

Comment: i thought this is the part of this question thats why i ask here.

Comment: @Ajay: Incorrect. You asked why you were getting a particular error. Post your other question separately.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType is found in the Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation library not in System.Net.NetworkInformation.