# Check if Internet is turned on in windows 8 phone app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, network-connection

I have a `Windows Phone 8` application. I need to check whether the device has internet connection before my application is launched or opened.

If Internet is `off` then it should direct the user to the `settings page` to `turn on the internet`.

```
public static bool checkNetworkConnection()
{
    var ni = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;

    bool IsConnected = false;
    if ((ni == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)|| (ni == NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma)|| (ni == NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm))
        IsConnected= true;
    else if (ni == NetworkInterfaceType.None)
        IsConnected= false;
    return IsConnected;
}
```

I tried this but it says:

```
NetworkInterfaceType not found in System.Net.NetworkInformation
```

can someone please guide me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting following error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877198/getting-following-error)

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877198/getting-following-error

Comment: Consider that the phone's internet connection state is always in flux. A nanosecond after your code has obtained its answer, the reality may be different. You need to write code that can *cope* with internet connection state changing *anyway*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
public static bool checkNetworkConnection()
{
    return NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
}
```

**Use this Namespace:** `using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;` for get network information.

Hope this helpful to you.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference) I get this error can you kindly help me....

Comment: Are you create Windows Phone 8 application ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
bool Connection = checkNetworkConnection()
if(Connection == false)
{ 
     // Here is ConnectionSettingTask to Go directly InternetSetting 
     ConnectionSettingsTask cst = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
     cst.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.Cellular;
     cst.Show(); 
}
public static bool checkNetworkConnection() 
{
    var ni = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
    bool IsConnected = false;
    if ((ni == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)|| (ni == NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma)|| (ni == NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm))
        IsConnected= true;
    else if (ni == NetworkInterfaceType.None)
         IsConnected= false;
    return IsConnected;
}
```